# Select Statement with Case

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use a case in a select statement.  I have never done this before, so I am unsure about the syntax.  Here is what I have so far:

```
CASE(column_name) 
      WHEN  NULL THEN 'Unnamed' 
      ELSE column_name 
END AS my_alias
```

How do I describe what will happen if a null value is encountered?

Comment: coalesce would be better actually `COALESCE(column_name, 'Unnamed')` - if this is SQL Server

Comment: use NVL() if in oracle, or NULLIF if mysql

Answer (score 2):

> How do I describe what will happen if a null value is encountered?

Use `COALESCE`, `NVL`, `ISNULL`, `NULLIF` or whatever function is appropriate for the the server software you'requerying:

```
COALESCE(column_name, 'Unnamed') AS my_alias

ISNULL(column_name, 'Unnamed') AS my_alias
```

If your `CASE` statement isn't working it's because `x = NULL` is ALWAYS false (even if `x` is `null`), so that case never gets used.  You could get it to work by using `IS NULL`:

```
CASE 
      WHEN column_name IS NULL THEN 'Unnamed' 
      ELSE column_name 
END AS my_alias
```

but `COALESCE` is cleaner.